# Sorting array that holds key of both numeric and string type

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am in a weird situation. Not sure why I am getting this result. 
I have an array 
`$x = array(
    1603 => 1976.8,
    1602 => 1976.8,
    1604 => 1976.8,
    1605 => 1933.8,
    1606 => 1667.6,
    1610 => 6535.3333333333,
    '1610-5' => 0.5,
    1611 => 18814.5
);` if I use ksort on this array the result is: 
`Array
(
    [1602] => 1976.8
    [1603] => 1976.8
    [1604] => 1976.8
    [1605] => 1933.8
    [1606] => 1667.6
    [1610-5] => 0.5
    [1610] => 6535.33333333
    [1611] => 18814.5
)`

But if I remove some initial items from this array e.g.

```
$x = array(
1604 => 1976.8,
1605 => 1933.8,
1606 => 1667.6,
1610 => 6535.3333333333,
'1610-5' => 0.5,
1611 => 18814.5
```

);

then ksort result for the same array is :

```
Array(
[1604] => 1976.8
[1605] => 1933.8
[1606] => 1667.6
[1610] => 6535.33333333
[1610-5] => 0.5
[1611] => 18814.5)
```

The difference in both is: in first result the array key values pair ('1610-5' => 0.5) is before (1610 => 6535.3333333333), but in next result the for the same array key values pair: ('1610-5' => 0.5) is after (1610 => 6535.3333333333). The same sorting is giving me different results. Why is this happening? I want that key '1610-5' should always come before key 1610. Which is coming correctly in my first sorting result. Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere.